# I/O with dictionary file on an Android Input Method (IME)

Tags: android, io, ime

I am currently developing an Android IME and I want to have a file that I will use it as a dictionary so I want to read and write it.

First of all, how do I import this file in the project?

Secondly, where is it storred in the device?

And lastly, I assume that it cannot be deleted, right?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a file that won't be modified, you can put it in assets folder. Users won't be able to delete it since  it's part of your application (.apk).  You can read it in using the following,

```
InputStream is = getAssets().open("yourDictionaryFileName");
```

Comment: One more question, if I want to add new words in this dictionary, I won't be able since it is placed in the assets folder? Thank you!

Comment: No, those files in assests folder are read-only.  You will need to use storage or database to store such data. The data stored outside your .apk file can be deleted by users though.  There's more information at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html.